# MATLAB: incorrect computation for 1D parabolic-elliptic system with pdepe

Tags: matlab, pde

I have found that MATLAB solves 1D parabolic-elliptic system incorrectly by using pdepe function when Robin boundary conditions are specified.

See, please:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829402/matlab-incorrect-computation-with-pdepe-for-parabolic-elliptic-system

If we use Dirichlet boundary conditions, the solution is correct.

Is my reasoning correct?

Some information about this in Russian: http://glebgrenkin.blogspot.ru/2014/05/matlab.html